# Access ObjC/C++ classes in Swift static library

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, static-libraries, module-map

I'm building this **Swift** static library: `OxfordLibrary` that I ultimately want to distribute using XCFramework.

I have some ObjC/C++ code that want to access from Swift.
Since We can't use ObjC bridging header in Static libraries (Throws errors when creating XCFramework), So I'm trying to use modulemap files.

So idea was keeping ObjC/C++ code base **internal / private to library** and only expose APIs via Swift.

So I created following:

```
/// FILE: module.modulemap

module OxfordLibrary {
    export *
}
```

```
/// FILE: module.private.modulemap

module OxfordLibrary_Private {
    umbrella header "OxfordLibrary-objc-umbrella.h"
    export *
}
```

I have set the `Defines Module: YES` and also set the swift `Seach Path` in build settings.

Now in my Main Swift file:

```
/// FILE: OxfordLibrary.swift

#import OxfordLibrary_Private

open OxfordLibrary{
    public static func foo() {
        SomeObjcClass.someObjcMehtod()    // Final aim
    }
}
```

Now without importing `OxfordLibrary_Private` I can't access `SomeObjcClass` in swift. Fine. After adding import it works.

This even builds correctly.

But when I create XCFramework from this and import that XCFramework to client app project, and I do `import OxfordLibrary` then it throws error **`OxfordLibrary_Private` module not found / not defined.**

After doing some research I found I need to copy modulemap files and headers to XCFramwork either in Modules folder or using -headers flag. It works if I do that.

But question is: Its private.modulemap supposed to be private and not avaible outside of the library?

Because now I can do `import OxfordLibrary_Private` in client app and access any ObjC method there.

Comment: dont understand the question you made it `public static`.. so to me it looks fine. is'nt the modulemap exactly meant to be able to know the symbols for in example debugging.

Comment: Just use SPM. It will create valid modulemaps for you.

Comment: @OI Sen yeah right, but in my client App I'm able to import and use all ObjC classes which I don't want. I have requirement where objective C class will be private. And Swift layer on top of them is only publicly available.

Comment: Actually @Cy-4AH I'm already using Tuist for this and that's enough. Because this library will be a part of a cross platform C++ library.

Comment: SPM is crossplatform